# How to make a javascript link bookmarkable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have several links on a page whereby I will like them to be distinguishable and bookmark able. eg.
On if I have a `contact.php` on that page I have several jQuery click events bonded to a link such that `www.mywebsite.com/contact.php#accountant` , `www.mywebsite.com/contact.php#developer`. When I click the links jQuery works.

But when I enter the links in a browser `www.mywebsite.com/contact.php#accountant` it does not take me straight to the accountant's contact details, rather I'm having to click the accountants contact again.

The page I'm working with is [here](http://types4u.org/ema/contact.php#)

I hope I was able to explain my problem. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
$('#contact' + $('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').get(0).className.replace('contact', '') ).fadeIn(3000);
```

to main.js file on the website, but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code inside your `$(document).ready(function(){...});` **but not inside the any click event** in your `js/main.js` file:

```
var numb = $('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').get(0);
if (numb != undefined) {
  numb = numb.className.replace('contact', '');
  $('#contact' + numb).fadeIn(3000);
}
```

This is essentially the same as line 23 in your `main.js` file - apart from that it will look for an anchor with a `href` that contains the `window.location.hash`, uses `.get(0)` to grab the actual DOM element, grabs the `className` and cleans out the `contact` part, using the value in place of where you originally used the `numb` var, then fading it in.

Comment: I added your code to main.js, but still not working. No content shows for the link that is clicked  http://types4u.org/ema/contact.php#

Comment: That's because there's nothing after the # - if you use http://types4u.org/ema/contact.php#pastor for instance it would work.

Comment: Okay, how can I make it work for all the links without repeating the line, since I have several links on the contact page.

Comment: There is actually something after the link. When you mouseover the links for example types4u.org/ema/contact.php#pastor shows

Comment: I've changed the code to make it only work when there is a `#` in the URL. It works for all the contact links.

Comment: @Olubunmi You need to put that code in the document ready - but **not** inside the click event. Put it at the top level or it won't work.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, but still does not work here. When I enter http://types4u.org/ema/contact.php#pastor the pastor's link does not open.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29740/discussion-between-leonard-challis-and-olubunmi)

Comment: is there a reason not to use pushstate?

Answer (score 3):

On page load read the window.location.hash, if it has a value, run your code.

Comment: Can you please provide a generic example ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to capture the search string of your address. For this, you can do this way:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Based on this, you need to activate the div.
  // This depends on the script you use.
} else {
  // Fragment doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a generic example ? Thanks